# Pandas dataframe with multiindex column - merge levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe, `grouped`, with multiindex columns as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

codes = ["one","two","three"];
colours = ["black", "white"];
textures = ["soft", "hard"];
N= 100 # length of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id' : range(1,N+1),
                    'weeks_elapsed' : [random.choice(range(1,25)) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'code' : [random.choice(codes) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'colour': [random.choice(colours) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'texture': [random.choice(textures) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'size': [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1,N+1)],
                    'scaled_size': [random.randint(100,1000) for i in range(1,N+1)]
                   },  columns= ['id', 'weeks_elapsed', 'code','colour', 'texture', 'size', 'scaled_size'])
grouped = df.groupby(['code', 'colour']).agg( {'size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax],'scaled_size': [np.sum, np.average, np.size, pd.Series.idxmax]}).reset_index()

>> grouped
    code colour     size                           scaled_size                         
                    sum    average  size  idxmax            sum    average  size  idxmax
0    one  black    1031  60.647059    17      81     185.153944  10.891408    17      47
1    one  white     481  37.000000    13      53     204.139249  15.703019    13      53
2  three  black     822  48.352941    17       6     123.269405   7.251141    17      31
3  three  white    1614  57.642857    28      50     285.638337  10.201369    28      37
4    two  black     523  58.111111     9      85      80.908912   8.989879     9      88
5    two  white     669  41.812500    16      78      82.098870   5.131179    16      78
[6 rows x 10 columns]
```

How can I flatten/merge the column index levels as: "Level1|Level2", e.g. `size|sum`, `scaled_size|sum`. etc? If this is not possible, is there a way to `groupby()` as I did above without creating multi-index columns?

Comment: This is just my opinion ,I feel like scott's is better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

There are varied (i.e., more pythonic) way to flatten a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) columns into single-level columns.

1. Use map and join with string column headers:

```
grouped.columns = grouped.columns.map('|'.join).str.strip('|')

print(grouped)
```

Output:

```
   code  colour   size|sum  size|average  size|size  size|idxmax  \
0    one   black       862     53.875000         16           14   
1    one   white       554     46.166667         12           18   
2  three   black       842     49.529412         17           90   
3  three   white       740     56.923077         13           97   
4    two   black      1541     61.640000         25           50   

   scaled_size|sum  scaled_size|average  scaled_size|size  scaled_size|idxmax  
0             6980           436.250000                16                  77  
1             6101           508.416667                12                  13  
2             7889           464.058824                17                  64  
3             6329           486.846154                13                  73  
4            12809           512.360000                25                  23
```

2. Use map with format for column headers that have numeric data types.

```
grouped.columns = grouped.columns.map('{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format)
```

Output:

```
   code| colour|  size|sum  size|average  size|size  size|idxmax  \
0    one   black       734     52.428571         14           30   
1    one   white      1110     65.294118         17           88   
2  three   black       930     51.666667         18            3   
3  three   white      1140     51.818182         22           20   
4    two   black       656     38.588235         17           77   
5    two   white       704     58.666667         12           17   

   scaled_size|sum  scaled_size|average  scaled_size|size  scaled_size|idxmax  
0             8229           587.785714                14                  57  
1             8781           516.529412                17                  73  
2            10743           596.833333                18                  21  
3            10240           465.454545                22                  26  
4             9982           587.176471                17                  16  
5             6537           544.750000                12                  49
```

3. Use list comprehension with f-string for Python 3.6+:

```
grouped.columns = [f'{i}|{j}' if j != '' else f'{i}' for i,j in grouped.columns]
```

Output:

```
    code colour  size|sum  size|average  size|size  size|idxmax  \
0    one  black      1003     43.608696         23           76   
1    one  white      1255     59.761905         21           66   
2  three  black       777     45.705882         17           39   
3  three  white       630     52.500000         12           23   
4    two  black       823     54.866667         15           33   
5    two  white       491     40.916667         12           64   

   scaled_size|sum  scaled_size|average  scaled_size|size  scaled_size|idxmax  
0            12532           544.869565                23                  27  
1            13223           629.666667                21                  13  
2             8615           506.764706                17                  92  
3             6101           508.416667                12                  43  
4             7661           510.733333                15                  42  
5             6143           511.916667                12                  49
```

Comment: it doesn't work when you have numeric columns 

`MultiIndex(levels=[[u'col_a', u'col_b', u'col_c'], [7950230.0, 12304568.0]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]],
           names=[lev, sublev'])`
it returns
`TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, float found`

Comment: @PabloA grouped.columns.map('{0[0]} | {0[1]}'.format)

Comment: brief update, as of at least v0.23, there's a `set_axis` method you can use: `renamed = df.set_axis(['|'.join(c) for c in df.columns], axis='columns', inplace=False)`

Comment: (and `axis='index'` would achieve similar results along multi-indexed rows)

Comment: To deal with numeric labels, I'm pretty sure `df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda tup: '|'.join(map(str, tup)))` would work

Comment: Hi Man Adjust this one `grouped.columns.map('|'.join).str.strip('|')` , BTW I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: It seems no differences btw `.map().str.strip()` & `.map()` after a test.

Comment: @SeanH .strip('|')    to strip off that last | on the end of code and colour where there is no second  level.

Answer (score 42):

you could always change the columns:

```
grouped.columns = ['%s%s' % (a, '|%s' % b if b else '') for a, b in grouped.columns]
```

Comment: if one of the columns in level 1 is equal to `0`, then the above expression will ignore it here :`b if b else ''`. Instead, I used `b != ''`, so `grouped.columns = ['%s%s' % (a, '|%s' % b if b != '' else '') for a, b in grouped.columns]`. This might be useful after using `groupby` which enumerates columns with numbers starting from 0.

Comment: there would be a problem with `None`s in that, so you'd have to do `if (b == 0 or b)`, but still a good call

Comment: @acusher, you right, though `if b is not None` should the simple way of expressing it...

Answer (score 17):

Based on Scott Boston's answer, 
little update(it will be work for 2 or more levels column):

```
temp.columns.map(lambda x: '|'.join([str(i) for i in x]))
```

Thank you, Boston!

Answer (score 6):

Full credit to suraj's concise answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72616083/317797

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: Yep, this is the best way!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain the operation, you can do

```py
out = (grouped.set_axis(grouped.columns.values, axis=1)
       # If you want to preserve order and strip the leading |
       .rename(columns=lambda col: '|'.join(col).strip('|'))
       # or if you don't care the extra |
       #.rename(columns='|'.join)
       # If you want to change the order and strip the leading |
       #.rename(columns=lambda col: f'{col[1]}|{col[0]}'.strip('|'))
       # or the order matters and you don't care the extra |
       #.rename(columns='{0[1]}|{0[0]}'.format)
       )
```

```
print(out)

    code colour  size|sum  size|average  size|size  size|idxmax  scaled_size|sum  scaled_size|average  scaled_size|size  scaled_size|idxmax
0    one  black       620     41.333333         15           24             7727           515.133333                15                  48
1    one  white       678     45.200000         15           37             8290           552.666667                15                  17
2  three  black       957     43.500000         22           34            11899           540.863636                22                   0
3  three  white       918     54.000000         17           12             8017           471.588235                17                  63
4    two  black      1009     63.062500         16           73             8954           559.625000                16                  35
5    two  white       601     40.066667         15           90             8729           581.933333                15                  96
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline with @scott-boston 's answer, in order to skip "Unnamed" columns to be merged use the following code

```
['|'.join(column)  if 'Unnamed' not in column[0] else column[1] for column in df.columns]
```