# Flatten 3 level MultiIndex Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the following pandas df:

```
Window         5                                                           15                                                          30                                                          45                                                  
feature      col0                col1                col2                col0                col1                col2                col0                col1                col2                col0                col1                col2          
metric       mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std      mean       std
0             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4       -0.878791  1.453479 -0.265591  0.712361  0.532332  0.894304       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
5       -0.748535  1.459479 -0.023874  1.250110  0.913094  1.134599       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

It has 3 levels which I would like to flatten to:

```
col0_5_mean  col0_5_std  col0_15_mean  col0_15_std  col0_30_mean  col0_30_std  col0_45_mean col0_45_std  col1_5_mean  col1_5_std...
```

So order should be feature_window_metric.

The df is generated by:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)


# def add_mean_std_cols3(df):
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3)).add_prefix('col')

windows = [5, 15, 30, 45]
stats = ['mean', 'std']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([windows, df.columns, stats], 
                                  names=['window', 'feature', 'metric'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((df.shape[0], len(cols))), columns=cols,
                   index=df.index)

for window in windows:
    df2.loc[:, window] = df.rolling(window=window).agg(stats).values

print df2
```

So far I tried the following solution among others:

From [Pandas dataframe with multiindex column - merge levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290297/pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-column-merge-levels)

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('|'.join)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, long found
```

I appreciate suggestions,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [1914]: df2.columns = ['{1}_{0}_{2}'.format(*c) for c in df2.columns]

In [1915]: df2.columns
Out[1915]:
Index([u'col0_5_mean', u'col0_5_std', u'col1_5_mean', u'col1_5_std',
       u'col2_5_mean', u'col2_5_std', u'col0_15_mean', u'col0_15_std',
       u'col1_15_mean', u'col1_15_std', u'col2_15_mean', u'col2_15_std',
       u'col0_30_mean', u'col0_30_std', u'col1_30_mean', u'col1_30_std',
       u'col2_30_mean', u'col2_30_std', u'col0_45_mean', u'col0_45_std',
       u'col1_45_mean', u'col1_45_std', u'col2_45_mean', u'col2_45_std'],
      dtype='object')

In [1916]: df2.head(2)
Out[1916]:
   col0_5_mean  col0_5_std  col1_5_mean  col1_5_std  col2_5_mean  col2_5_std  \
0          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN
1          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN

   col0_15_mean  col0_15_std  col1_15_mean  col1_15_std     ...       \
0           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN     ...
1           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN     ...

   col1_30_mean  col1_30_std  col2_30_mean  col2_30_std  col0_45_mean  \
0           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN           NaN
1           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN           NaN

   col0_45_std  col1_45_mean  col1_45_std  col2_45_mean  col2_45_std
0          NaN           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN
1          NaN           NaN          NaN           NaN          NaN

[2 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks so much! Do you know where I could learn more about this type of formating?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `map` with `format`:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('{0[0]} | {0[1]} | {0[2]}'.format)
```

Comment: @Diego Index(['5 | col0 | mean', '5 | col0 | std', '5 | col1 | mean',
       '5 | col1 | std', '5 | col2 | mean', '5 | col2 | std',
       '15 | col0 | mean', '15 | col0 | std', '15 | col1 | mean',
       '15 | col1 | std', '15 | col2 | mean', '15 | col2 | std',
       '30 | col0 | mean', '30 | col0 | std', '30 | col1 | mean',
       '30 | col1 | std', '30 | col2 | mean', '30 | col2 | std',
       '45 | col0 | mean', '45 | col0 | std', '45 | col1 | mean',
       '45 | col1 | std', '45 | col2 | mean', '45 | col2 | std'],
      dtype='object')