# What does df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format) mean exactly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I came across this very helpful answer to a question that I had about merging multilevel indexed columns into a single level
([Pandas dataframe with multiindex column - merge levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290297/pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-column-merge-levels)), and one of the pythonic ways that was suggested was to use this particular line of code,

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format)
```

where df is the dataframe with multilevel indexed columns.

It basically converted columns into

```
index1|subindex1  index1|subindex2  index1|subindex3  index2|subindex1
1                 1                 2                 5
2                 1                 2                 4
```

and so on.

My question is whether someone can explain to me why writing
`'{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format` works but when I tried writing `'{}|{}'.format([0],[1])`, I get a type error.

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `'{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format(['index1', 'subindex1'])` as a working example, and read [the docs on `str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: `'{0[0]}|{0[1]}'.format` is a function (or, more accurately, a method). `'{}|{}'.format([0],[1])` is not a function, it's a function call that returns a string. Obviously, you can't pass a string to the `map` function.