# Pandas reshape dataframe by adding a column level based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

I have a pandas dataframe and I would like to **add a column level** to split specific columns (`metric_a`, `metric_b`, `metric_c`) into several subcolumns based on the value of another column (`parameter`).

---

Current data format:

```
    participant param   metric_a    metric_b    metric_c
0   alice       a       0,700       0,912       0,341
1   alice       b       0,736       0,230       0,370
2   bob         a       0,886       0,364       0,995
3   bob         b       0,510       0,704       0,990
4   charlie     a       0,173       0,462       0,709
5   charlie     b       0,085       0,950       0,807
6   david       a       0,676       0,653       0,189
7   david       b       0,823       0,524       0,430
```

Wanted data format:

```
    participant metric_a        metric_b        metric_c
                a       b       a       b       a       b
0   alice       0,700   0,736   0,912   0,230   0,341   0,370
1   bob         0,886   0,510   0,364   0,704   0,995   0,990
2   charlie     0,173   0,085   0,462   0,950   0,709   0,807
3   david       0,676   0,823   0,653   0,524   0,189   0,430
```

---

I have tried

```
df.set_index(['participant', 'param']).unstack(['param'])
```

which gives me a close result but not satisfies me as I want to keep a single-level index and `participant` a regular column.

```
            metric_a        metric_b        metric_c
param       a       b       a       b       a       b
participant
alice       0,700   0,736   0,912   0,230   0,341   0,370
bob         0,886   0,510   0,364   0,704   0,995   0,990
charlie     0,173   0,085   0,462   0,950   0,709   0,807
david       0,676   0,823   0,653   0,524   0,189   0,430
```

---

I have the intuition that `groupby()` or `pivot_table()` functions could do the job but cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) specifying `col_level` parameter:

```
df.set_index(['participant', 'param']).unstack('param').reset_index(col_level=0)
```

[out]

```
      participant metric_a        metric_b        metric_c       
param                    a      b        a      b        a      b
0           alice    0,700  0,736    0,912  0,230    0,341  0,370
1             bob    0,886  0,510    0,364  0,704    0,995  0,990
2         charlie    0,173  0,085    0,462  0,950    0,709  0,807
3           david    0,676    NaN    0,653    NaN    0,189    NaN
4           heidi      NaN  0,823      NaN  0,524      NaN  0,430
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
Doing so I cannot access the `participant` column anymore:
`>>> df['participant']`
[out] `KeyError: 'participant'`

I would rather have this kind of data structure:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290297/pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-column-merge-levels (`grouped` in the question)

Comment: @Étienne apologies, change to `col_level=0` and `df['participant']` should work