# Pandas add column level which increases total columns count

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I created a dataframe as follows.

```
myidx=['idx1','idx2','idx3']
mycols=['a','b','c','d']
df=pd.DataFrame(index=myidx,columns=mycols)
```

```
        a    b    c    d
idx1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
idx2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
idx3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then I would like to add a new column level with `n` repeated values. Let say:

```
mycolsnewlvl=['foo','bar','baz']
```

The expected output would be:

```
             a              b              c              d   
       foo  bar  baz  foo  bar  baz  foo  bar  baz  foo  bar  baz
idx1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
idx2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
idx3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40225796/3284713)

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['foo','bar','baz']])
```

But it returns:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 24 elements

I also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849519/pandas-reshape-dataframe-by-adding-a-column-level-based-on-the-value-of-another) but couldn't make it work for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for repeat columns by `MultiIndex` values:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['foo','bar','baz']])

df = df.reindex(mux, axis=1)
print (df)
       a           b           c           d        
     foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz
idx1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
idx2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
idx3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```