# pandas resampled time series data - multiple agg functions on the same column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily timeseries data that I resampled to weekly data and summed the 'sales' column:

```
df_weekly = df.resample('W', on='TransxDate').agg({'sales': 'sum'})
```

How can also get 'count' of sales? If I use

```
df_weekly = df.resample('W', on='TransxDate').agg({'sales': 'sum', 'sales': 'count'})
```

I only get the count. If I reverse the order, I only get the sum. I suspect the problem is using the same column name with multiple functions. Is there a way to specify the output column name so that I can perform multiple agg functions on the same column? Or some other solution?

Comment: Use a list with aggregating column like this:  `df.resample('W',on='TransxDate')['sales'].agg(['sum', 'count'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.resample('W', on='TransxDate')['sales'].agg(['sum', 'count'])
```

or you can create a multilevel index with the column aggregating then the functions as level 1. By, using double brackets `[[]]`.

```
df.resample('2M', on='Date1')[['Number']].agg(['sum', 'count'])
```

Comment: Both work, thanks. And I was able to extend this to multiple columns using `df_weekly = df.resample('W', on='TransxDate')[['sales', 'items']].agg(['sum', 'count'])`  Now I just need to read up on how to work with the resulting multi-index(?) dataframe.

Comment: @jub you can flatten the multiIndex using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43859132/6361531).  Or you can select the using tuples with loc.