# Flatten multiindex dataframe levels and remove string from end of column names if contains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
np.arange(2, 11).reshape(-1, 3),
index=list('ABC'),
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    ['data1', 'data2','data3'],
    ['F', 'K',''],
    ['', '','']
], names=['meter', 'Sleeper',''])
).rename_axis('Index')

df

meter   data1 data2 data3
Sleeper     F     K                             
Index                    
A           2     3     4
B           5     6     7
C           8     9    10
```

So I want to join level names and flatted the data
following this solution [Pandas dataframe with multiindex column - merge levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290297/pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-column-merge-levels)

```
  df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('|')
  df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Getting this

```
 Index  data1_F_    data2_K_    data3__
0   A     2            3         4
1   B     5            6         7
2   C     8            9        10
```

but I dont want those `_` end of the column names so I added

```
df.columns = df.columns.apply(lambda x: x[:-1] if x.endswith('_') else x)
df
```

But got

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'

How can I combine `map` and `apply` (flatten the column names and remove `_` at the end of the column names in one run ?

expected output

```
  Index data1_F     data2_K   data3
0   A     2            3         4
1   B     5            6         7
2   C     8            9        10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('_')
df
Out[132]: 
       data1_F  data2_K  data3
Index                         
A            2        3      4
B            5        6      7
C            8        9     10
```