# Pandas question where I have Object as Column Name how to call

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When importing with read_csv, I added the first 2 rows as headers in my dataframe so I have what I think is an Object as all my column names.

For example when I type

```
df.iloc[:,0]
```

I get the following to be returned.

```
Name: (RECORD, Unnamed: 0_level_1), Length: 36000, dtype: int64
```

I'm unsure how to use

```
df.LOC["ColName" = "value"]
```

Usually for ColName I'd put a single string that is usually the column name. I'm unsure for what do I put for ColName ?

Edit:

```
>>>> df.head(2).to_dict()
{('RECORD', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'): {0: 1, 1: 2}, ('TIME/DATE', 'Unnamed: 
1_level_1'): {0: '19:55:48.52  09/30/22  ', 1: '19:55:48.62  09/30/22  
'}, ('ALARM OR MESSAGE', 'Unnamed: 2_level_1'): {0: 'NO ALARMS                   
', 1: 'NO ALARMS'}
```

I tried to convert

```
df['TIME']= pd.to_datetime(df['TIME/DATE'],, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', infer_datetime_format=True)
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

I believe it's because the Heading is an object.

Comment: Could you provide your `df.head(2).to_dict()` ? i.e. a [mcve]

Comment: I added it after the Edit:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have set up a multi-level column index by specifying the first 2 rows of your CSV file as headers, however it seems the second row didn't have any useful information in it (hence the `Unnamed...` column names). You can get rid of that using [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```py
df = df.droplevel(level=1,axis=1)
```

This gives:

```
   RECORD                TIME/DATE ALARM OR MESSAGE
0       1  19:55:48.52  09/30/22          NO ALARMS
1       2    19:55:48.62  09/30/22        NO ALARMS
```

You should then clean up the extra spaces on your `TIME/DATE` column before processing with the appropriate [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```py
df['TIME/DATE'] = df['TIME/DATE'].str.strip()
df['TIME']= pd.to_datetime(df['TIME/DATE'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f  %m/%d/%y')
```

Output:

```
   RECORD              TIME/DATE ALARM OR MESSAGE                    TIME
0       1  19:55:48.52  09/30/22        NO ALARMS 2022-09-30 19:55:48.520
1       2  19:55:48.62  09/30/22        NO ALARMS 2022-09-30 19:55:48.620
```

If you need the multi-level index, you can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to access the column values:

```py
df.loc[:, ('TIME/DATE', 'Unnamed:1_level_1')] = df.loc[:, ('TIME/DATE', 'Unnamed:1_level_1')].str.strip()
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, ('TIME/DATE', 'Unnamed:1_level_1')], format='%H:%M:%S.%f  %m/%d/%y')
```

Output:

```
              RECORD              TIME/DATE   ALARM OR MESSAGE                    TIME
  Unnamed: 0_level_1      Unnamed:1_level_1 Unnamed: 2_level_1
0                  1  19:55:48.52  09/30/22          NO ALARMS 2022-09-30 19:55:48.520
1                  2  19:55:48.62  09/30/22          NO ALARMS 2022-09-30 19:55:48.620
```

Comment: I need that second row later on in the dataset - is there a way to just concatenate the two entries into one entry?

Comment: @user3042850 see my edit to retain the multi-level index; or you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290297/pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-column-merge-levels for merging the levels